# Fedora + Plank + App launcher

Tags: fedora20

This is how I managed to use 'plank' + an applications launcher in Fedora 20. It workds, but is this 'tip' with 'dbus' appropriate and future proof ?

- Install 'plank' with: sudo yum install plank; (maybe RPM fusion is needed)
- Remove the 'plank' icon with: rm ~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/plank.dockitem
- Link the launcher with: nano ~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/show-apps.dockitem
- And add the next text:

  ```
  [PlankItemsDockItemPreferences]
  Launcher=file:///usr/share/applications/show-apps.desktop
  ```
- Create the launcher with: sudo nano /usr/share/applications/show-apps.desktop
- Add the next text:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0
  Type=Application
  Name=Show Apps
  Comment=Show applications menu
  Exec=gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.overview.toggle();Main.overview.viewSelector._showAppsButton.checked = true;';
  Icon=view-grid-symbolic
  Path=
  Terminal=false
  ```

Comment: You should use http://ask.fedoraproject.org/ instead because it is more appropriate

Comment: I'm on GNOME 3.18 under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and this method works fine. It's hackish, but it works.